# What drives SE's high international user engagement?

Tags: discussion, users

For a company based in New York, founded by two Americans, I see more international user activity on Stack Exchange than most other American websites.  Specifically, I encounter what seems to be a disproportionately high amount of international content on ***Sports*** and ***Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair*** than I've experienced at other social or user-engaged websites.

For the ***Sports*** page, [Cricket and football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tags) are both higher-ranking tags than any of the big four American sports.  A large portion of the questions specifically address cricket and association football.

Though the ***Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair*** page doesn't have any outstandingly international tags as a tangible example, I'll reference my experiences.  I've seen more international verbiage on this site than any other automotive forum or Q&A arena (*bonnet*, *tyre*, *petrol*, etc.).  I've also seen many references to vehicle models and trim levels that do not exist in the US, again, more than I have in my time in other automotive websites.

Answer (score 7):

It all boils down to the way they have grown through time.

StackOverflow was a huge hit. So, it's incredibly huge amount of users is justifiable.

The way **moderation** is done in the SE sites deserve much of the credit. The quality of the posts in most sites are so good, that they pop up in the top search results for most buzz words, and common phrases.

Many sites are slowly turning into dumps of clutter, without proper moderation. Having been a very early adopter of Quora, I feel very sad to say that my time spent on Quora is slowly decreasing, as the site accumulates more and more unmoderated clutter.

For example, I am a data scientist in India. I had a doubt in statistics, which bugged me a lot. I typed the relevant words from the doubt on Google. Then, I stumbled upon CrossValidated, the stats site of SO.

That was the first time I realized there were other sites in the network, apart from just SO. And, I also got my doubt cleared, both from the post and from the chat. (**User Onboarding succesfully done**)

Now, the site should try and retain me as a long-time user, which is the most difficult part. And that is excellently being done by the way the sites are moderated. I enjoyed myself at CV, both on chat and answering questions. (**User Retention succesfully done**)

My curiosity got the better of me, and I started wandering into a lot of other site, like WorkPlace, SFF (<-- being a huge HP fan myself), etc. I enjoyed my time in almost all of them. Thus I became a promoter of SO (the result being this answer).

So, SO has a similar user conversion journey like most startups, and is consistently polishing it.

Answer (score 6):

I think one reason is the collaborative nature of the sites. If someone who speaks (writes) English as a second language asks a question on a site, and someone else cleans up the English, they end up getting an answer. Maybe some upvotes too. They feel welcome. If one site works for them, there's a good confidence another site in the network, with the same mechanics, will work too.

Also, plenty of sites draw moderators from around the world for practical reasons related to time zones. But a natural side effect is that people from around the world are likely to feel represented and included in a way that the phrase "a company based in New York, founded by two Americans" wouldn't naturally evoke.